using httpGet in onSuccess in a Conditional Authentication setup
I set up a scenario where a user logs in using their username and password, and then using an httpGet call inside the executeStep.onSuccess I wanted to check if the user is allowed. The issue is that onSuccess or onFail of httpGet is never called, yet authentication continues as if everything is ok.
The script is like this:
executeStep(1, {
    onSuccess: function(context) {
        var user = context.currentKnownSubject;

        Log.info("before request");
        httpGet('https://my.custom.service/check?' + user.username, {
            onSuccess: function(context, data) {
                Log.info("can go");
                executeStep(2);
            },
            onFail: function(context, data) {
                Log.info("failed");
            }
        })
        Log.info("after request");
    }

I see "before request" and "after request" messages but no "can go" or "failed" messages. In my opinion, the process should wait until httpGet is complete, but this does not seem to be the case. How can I make the script to wait for the service call and act accordingly?

it seems request falls in a timeout and an undocumented handler onTimeout is called. Issue is that service works, and works fast so there should be no timeout

The issue you're experiencing is that the httpGet call is asynchronous, which means that the script doesn't wait for the HTTP request to finish before continuing to execute subsequent steps. Because the script continues immediately, it logs "before request" and "after request" without waiting for the HTTP response. This causes the authentication to continue as if everything is OK, without checking if the user is allowed.
To make the script wait for the result of the httpGet call, you can utilize JavaScript's built-in mechanisms for handling asynchronous operations. One approach is to use async/await if your environment supports them.
executeStep(1, {
onSuccess: async function(context) {
    var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
    
    Log.info("before request");

    // Wrap the httpGet in a promise and await its result
    try {
        var data = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            httpGet('https://my.custom.service/check?' + user.username, {
                onSuccess: function(context, data) {
                    Log.info("can go");
                    resolve(data);  // Resolve the promise on success
                },
                onFail: function(context, data) {
                    Log.info("failed");
                    reject(data);  // Reject the promise on failure
                }
            });
        });
        
        // Continue to the next step after successful check
        executeStep(2);
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle the error case if the check fails
        Log.info("User is not allowed or service failed");
    }

    Log.info("after request");
}
});

Hope this will help.

Unfortunately, wso2 conditional authentication scripts do not support sync/await syntax. Thank you for the answer though

The issue was that the result was a JSON array, but httpGet method expects a JSON object, and it does not receive, it silently fails
